# Elasticsearch NEST retrieve the internal _id metadata field

Tags: search, request, metadata, elasticsearch

im just getting up to speed with the basics of elasticsearch...

indexing works fine but now that i want to do an incremental index on selected records that have changed in a set time span so i need to get the unique auto generated _id from the indexed record.

when looping through each content item i will be able to retrieve our own id field that we set within the class poco with -

```
var request = new GetRequest("mycontentindex", "contentindexclass", contentInsert.ESUniqueKey)
            {
                Fields = new PropertyPathMarker[] { "content", "name", "eSUniqueKey" }
            };
```

what i then want to do is to get the internal metadata _id from the current record as this is the field that is used when the client.Update is done...

does anyone know how i would get this?

im working with the NEST API within .NET / C#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ElasticSearch and Nest: Why amd I missing the id field on a query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33834141/elasticsearch-and-nest-why-amd-i-missing-the-id-field-on-a-query)