# ElasticSearch and Nest: Why am I missing the id field on a query?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I created a simple object that represents a Meeting that has elements such as time, location, name, topic, etc and indexed it in ElasticSearch via Nest. It has an Id field that I leave blank so that ES can generate them.

Later on I retrieved all the documents that are missing GEO coordinates so that I may update them. All my returned elements still have null for the id field and when I update them back to ES it creates new documents for them.

What am I missing here that makes all my id's null?

Thank you

Here is the Meeting class (the id prop is redundant but I tried it anyway)

```
[ElasticType(IdProperty = "Id")]
    public class Meeting
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Day { get; set; }
        public string Town { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string OriginalTime { get; set; }
        public string OriginalTimeCleaned { get; set; }
        public string Handicap { get; set; }
        public string FormattedAddress { get; set; }
        public Coordinates Coordinates { get; set; }
        public List<MeetingTime> Times = new List<MeetingTime>();
        public bool IsProcessed { get; set; }    
    }
```

Here is how I retrieve meetings

```
 public static List<Meeting> GetAddressesWithMissingCoordinates()
        {

            var result = Client.Search<Meeting>(s => s
                .Index("meetings")
                .AllTypes()
                .Query(p => p.Filtered(f => f.Filter(x => x.Missing(c => c.Coordinates)))));


            return result.Documents.ToList();
        }
```

Here is my update statement, Id is null

```
 public static void UpdateMeetingCoordinates(Meeting meeting, Coordinates coordinates)
        {
            meeting.Coordinates = coordinates;

            var response = Client.Index(meeting, u => u
                .Index("meetings")
                .Type("meeting")
                //.Id(meeting.Id.ToString())
                .Refresh()
                );

            Console.WriteLine(response);
        }
```

I've tried partial updates as well with no luck.

Comment: Can you post your Meeting POCO and any other code snippets that may help?

Answer (score 8):

There is a way to get the internal id, as described in [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1293#issuecomment-88151908) requesting this very feature.

Rather than using `response.Documents`, do this instead:

```
var results = response.Hits.Select(hit =>
    {
        var result = hit.Source;
        result.Id = hit.Id;
        return result;
    });
```

Comment: As of Jan 26, 2015 the elastic team stated in the [same issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1293#issuecomment-175410209) that this will be the implementation moving forward.  I ended up using Hits rather than Documents to retrieve the Id.

Answer (score 4):

Elasticsearch sets an `"_id"` meta-data parameter (for which it chooses a value if you don't specify one), but it doesn't set that value *in* your document source.

To illustrate, if I create a trivial index:

```
PUT /test_index
```

then give it a couple of documents, without specifying `"_id"`:

```
POST /test_index/doc/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"id":null,"name":"doc1"}
{"index":{}}
{"id":null,"name":"doc2"}
```

and then search:

```
POST /test_index/_search
```

this is what I get back:

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "AVEmuVlmj_RE0PsHCpza",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "id": null,
               "name": "doc2"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "AVEmuVlmj_RE0PsHCpzZ",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "id": null,
               "name": "doc1"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Notice that the `"_id"` meta-data parameter was set for both documents, but the `"id"` field I passed is unchanged. That's because, as far as Elasticsearch is concerned, `"id"` is just another document field.

(here is the code I used: http://sense.qbox.io/gist/777dafae88311c4105453482050c64d69ccd09db)

Comment: ok that makes sense. Do you know how I can update documents via Nest if my Id field never populates?

Comment: If you want to update your docs, I'd suggest using some sort of Id field there, so you can reindex same document using very same Id(it will overwrite that previous doc). Update by Query is not supported afaik.

Comment: As I said in my original question I do have an ID field and its not being populated